# make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop. [ubuntu]

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake

I'm trying to build this 
https://github.com/patrikhuber/eos
but I'm having troubles.

The instructions are pretty simple, as it says on gitHub

To build:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/patrikhuber/eos.git
mkdir build && cd build # creates a build directory next to the 'eos' folder
cmake -G "<your favourite generator>" ../eos -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install/
make && make install # or open the project file and build in an IDE like Visual Studio
```

I'm using "Ninja" as generator and it looks like the cmake part goes through successfully as I get

```
-- Configuring done

-- Generating done

-- Build files have been written to: /home/francesco/eos/build
```

That's where things stop "working" for me, or where I fail to understand what's next. Following the instructions, I type

```
make && make install
```

and I get this message

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I looked around for solutions but I don't really understand what I am supposed to do: I tried
    ./configure

but I'm getting

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Anyone can please help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked in the `build` directory? Perhaps you missed a step (or the author of the instruction missed it), to change directory to `build`?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I am executing this from the build directory. I am moving to the build directory as soon as it's created with mkdir build && cd build

Comment: You use "Ninja"  generator, so buildind the project is performed with `ninja`, not with `make`.

Comment: So which one should I use? I don't see "make" in the generator list

Comment: @Francesco you can invoke "cmake -G" to show all platform available generators - of course generator require the tool/ide is installer. You can use 'Ninja' as well - but this is 3rd party tool and you have to install/download it.
May be read this man-page: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-generators.7.html

Comment: Thank you all so much, I managed to build and install!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always depends on your CMake "Generator". The 'make' is linux/mingw tool/command. For VisualStudio you can use nmake or sln/proj generated stuff.

More reliable could be utilize CMake for building i.e. for "NMake Makefiles" generator:

```
cmake --build <build folder> --target install
```

or

```
cmake --build <build folder> --config release --target install
```

for VisualStudio generator

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved by tinkering with locations for `cmake` and `make`. Here's what I used:

```bash
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
make
```

I believe `/usr/local` is the default location (see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html))